# Firebase Auth and Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a question with Firebase, I'm new to this. I would like to return the user's name when I login, but that name is in Database and I would like to return only the name, of course, coinciding with the email found in the authentication, which is also in the Database. The idea I have is to compare the email from the database with the Auth and if it is true, give me the name. But I would not know how to develop it. Solutions?
Thank you

Comment: I compare it so that I can receive the name that has as the node the email. Because in the Auth I can not insert a name and then return that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this, you need to use a model class that looks like this:

```
public class UserModel implements Serializable {
    private String userEmail;
    private String userName;

    public UserModel() {}

    public UserModel(String userEmail, String userName) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {return userEmail;}
    public String getUserName() {return userName;}
}
```

To actually add a user, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
UserModel userModel = new UserModel("john@email,com", "John");
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
usersRef.child(uid).setValue(userModel);
```

Your database structure will look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- users
         |
         --- uid
              |
              --- userEmail: "john@email,com"
              |
              --- userName: "John"
```

Furthermore, to get back the `userName`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference uidRef = usersRef.child(uid);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            String userName = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
            nombre.setText(userName);
            Log.d("TAG", userName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

If you are interested, I have also exaplained in one of my tutorials step by step, the entire authentication process using **[Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwgMWBhObDw&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=5)** and **[Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIRt9Ts0fRU&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=6)**.

Comment: What is ds and String.class?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my answer. `ds` was wrong. I edited with: `dataSnapshot` and String class is used for casting. Does it work now?

Comment: Please keep me posted.

Comment: I worked like this:

Comment: `code` eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                nombre.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("datos").getValue()));

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Comment: @AlexMamo i have a little bit another situation in this question, can u check please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to go into that much trouble.
Follow [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users) and it might help you. You don't need to do a email matching. Firebase provides unique user ID for each user. Once a user register into your system firebase provides that ID. You just have to save it in database as the primary key for that user. Then you can get data from your database using user Id. User Id can be fetched in any place using `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid()`

Comment: How can I do it, how to get the authentication id to place it in the database?

Comment: You can use following code get the current logged used it. After you registered a user using any registration method in firebase you can use this code segment.  `FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
authenticatedId = currentFirebaseUser.getUid()`

Comment: Thanks, but placing the uid as child, as I recover a specific data and I wanted to place it only in a TextView?