# Create unique notes for users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

Implemented in the application firebase authentication. As well as the ability to add and delete records. But when I go with another account, the records are the same everywhere.

Q: how can I create my own records for each authorized user?

Now have smth like this:

[image]

As I understood from the comment I need to add another field to my structure: "users". And ultimately get type `target-list - > users - > targets`

But for example in my main activity I select as follows:
`databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("targets")`

How do I understand here I have to change the structure?

**UPD**:
I tried to to next:

```
private fun updateListData() {
    val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid ?: ""
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("targets").child(uid)
    getTargetsFromDb()
}
```

and in getTargetsFromDb():

```
private fun getTargetsFromDb() {
    databaseReference?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (targetSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                val target = targetSnapshot.getValue(Target::class.java)
                target?.let { targetList.add(it) }
            }
            recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d("some", "Error trying to get targets for ${databaseError.message}")
        }
    })
}
```

And get next structure:

[image]

Comment: You have to add a one layer on top of targets with the user-id key. Doing this every user have their own list of targets

Comment: @Murdok thx, I have updated the question, if not difficult, please see

Comment: Why are you using as the unique identifier a pushed id rather than the `uid` that is coming from the authentication process?

Comment: @AlexMamo But how can I use the one that comes from the authentication process?

Comment: @AlexMamo I so understand I can use it in `onActivityResult()` when I successfully pass authorization?

Comment: As explained **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253026/firebase-auth-and-database/49256810)** and in Kotlin `val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid` once you are authenticated.

Comment: @AlexMamo Updated question, but I miss something

Comment: Shouln't be `.getReference("users")`? The uid is used under `Users` node right? Not under `targets`.

Comment: @AlexMamo yep, i made smth like this: `if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid ?: ""
                val userName = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.displayName
                val userEmail = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.email
                val userModel = User(userName, userEmail)
                val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                val usersRef = rootRef.child("users")
                usersRef.child(uid).setValue(userModel)`

Comment: That's good. The result in the database is as expected.

Comment: @AlexMamo no problem with this. The problem is to create targets for each user

Comment: In that case, why aren't you changing that pushed id with the `uid`? Will solve the problem.

Comment: @AlexMamo but i use here: `val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid ?: ""
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("targets").child(uid)`

Comment: I the screenshot that you provided, you aren't. I see those pushed ids.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190699/discussion-between-morozov-and-alex-mamo).

Answer (score 0):

Accodring to your comments and messages, you want to create targets for each user separately. Using your actual structure you have the users and targets separately. To solve this, I recommend you another database structure that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- targets
       |
       --- uid
            |
            --- pushedId
            |    |
            |    --- description: "some description"
            |    |
            |    --- name: "Vadim"
            |
            --- pushedId
                 |
                 --- description: "another description"
                 |
                 --- name: "Morozov"
```

To get all the targets that corresponde to a particular user, simply use the following query:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
val uidRef = rootRef.child("targets").child(uid)
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

An alternative database structure might be:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- targets
        |
        --- pushedId
        |    |
        |    --- description: "some description"
        |    |
        |    --- name: "Vadim"
        |    |
        |    --- uid: "VDMQ ... 0nw1"
        |
        --- pushedId
             |
             --- description: "another description"
             |
             --- name: "Svetlana"
             |
             --- uid: "eluk ... PJu1"
```

As you can see, it has a level less than the previous structure. Now, to get all the targets that corresponde to a particular user, please use the following query:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
val targetsRef = rootRef.child("targets").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid)
targetsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

So it's up to you to decide which one is better for you.

Comment: in the second case you get the Query for `targetsRef`.
In the first case, alas, still another structure is obtained.
When authenticating, do I need to create a user in the database?

Comment: Sure you need to create a user in the database. I didn't add the `users` node because of space but you definetely should add it.

Comment: Hi Morozov! Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Updated question. Can u check please? Maybe I should share my test project. in git as an example?

Comment: As you probably know, the rule in this community is to ask a question and if you get an answer, to solve your problem you should make your own attempt given the information in the answer and ask another question if something else comes up. So I rolled back to the previous version.

Comment: as you can see from the question that I updated, your decision did not help me, apparently I'm missing something, but alas, to determine the error has not yet happened

Comment: Editing your question over and over again with every problem that you encounter is not a solution. That's why I recommended you to ask another question, in the moment you encounter a new problem. We stick to one question at a time.

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect your notes. The problem remained the same

Comment: Between the time you get a solution to a problem and when you actually solve it, you can face many other coding challenges and in the same time, the main problem can remain the same. So neither me nor the other users can help you with all the problems that you face during your development, that's why you should take the time and ask a separate question for every problem separately.

Comment: I rolled back your question because the database structure has been modified due the changes that you made in your code. So those changes become a new problem that must be treated separately. Hope you undestand this point of view. So if  you want to get help from me or other Firebase developers, please post a separate question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for every issue separately.

Comment: Is there everything alright, have you solved the case?