# Users node not found in database after authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I used Google sign in authentication in my Android app. After authentication success, no "users" node was found in real-time database. Do I have to create it manually? If yes then how?
I want users node and within it Uid of each users.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253026/firebase-auth-and-database/49256810)** is how you can  add a user to a Firebase realtime database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Authentication** and **Databases** are two different things. Authentication would provide a bunch of data regarding the user that you can later upload to the database. One popular use case of authentication is that you can check whether a user is a new user or old and whether they are signed in or not in the `onCreate` or `onStart` method of your main screen. For more info regarding authentication [see here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start). If you want to read and write data to the database then refer to [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Answer (score 0):

Authentications don't create database references, you have to create it yourself. The Authentication only creates a user in the Auth section of Firebase.